# Best way to convert a specific string to array

Tags: c#

I made a control

and I generated a string with javascript from a javascript array using

```
Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(array);
```

this is the string generated

```
"["name", "Code", "Alias"]"
```

this string is send to my control with a postback.

Now I need to know the best way to make an array from this string using C#

Comment: you're trying way too hard man.  What web technology are you using to get from the javascript back to the c#?  If it's something like WebAPI or mvc then there is just standard model binding.  I wasn't the down-voter, but you got downvoted because the question is somewhat half-baked.

Comment: I'm creating an advanced text input control using the scriptcontrol in C#. I have a lot of data in my javascript but I need some data set back when postback occures. thats why I added this string into a hiddenfield which postback capture and my textcontrol get its new changed settings after postback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)  class:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var array = serializer.Deserialize<string[]>(yourString);
```

Note: You need to add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions.dll`

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. I already knew about the split but I thought there was some sort of already built in function for it. Thx a lot man

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] splitByComma = yourString.Split(',');
foreach(String splitString in splitByComma)
{
    splitString.Replace("\"","").Replace("[","").Replace("]","");
}
```